# node.js:: what does hostname do in `listen` function?

Tags: node.js

I own two domains, abc.com and xyz.com (not the real ones I own, but they work as an example). They both point to the same ip address. The following is my server js file:

```
var sys=require('sys'),
  http=require('http'),
  settings=require('./settings');



var srv = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var body="<b>Hello World!</b>"
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'content-length': body.length,
          'content-type': 'text/html',
          'stream': 'keep-alive',
          'accept': '*/*'
          }
      );
    res.end(body);
  });

srv.listen(8000, 'abc.com' ); // (settings.port, settings.hostname);
```

I then visit http://abc.com:8000/ and http://xyz.com:8000/  and they both display the webpage. I thought that I would only be able to see the page on abc.com since that's what I set as the hostname.

However, when I put '127.0.0.1' as the hostname, then I can only view the page via wget on the server itself.

So what *does* the hostname parameter do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following segment of code inside net.js that defines the listen function is pertinent:

```
// the first argument is the port, the second an IP    
var port = arguments[0];
dns.lookup(arguments[1], function (err, ip, addressType) {
  if (err) {
    self.emit('error', err);
  } else {
    self.type = addressType == 4 ? 'tcp4' : 'tcp6';
    self.fd = socket(self.type);
    bind(self.fd, port, ip);
    self._doListen();
  }
});
```

So basically providing a url as the hostname parameter does not allow shared hosting. All node.js does is do the work for you of resolving a hostname to an ip address -- and since in my case both domains point to the same ip, both will work.

For me to do shared hosting, I must find another way.

Comment: and did you find another way?

Comment: @pksorensen, there are other questions that deal with [virtual hosting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503841/virtual-hosting-with-standalone-node-js-server) on Node.js.

Comment: It's really an odd way that node does this, because there is no concept of binding a server to an *actual* hostname.  What is happening is that node is is binding an IP address to the server.  The whole DNS lookup obscures this and makes the documentation less clear (even six years later).  I don't know why they don't just call the argument `ip_address` and do away with the lookup.  Virtual hosting is a whole different ballgame that has nothing to do with what's going on here.