# Virtual hosting with standalone node.js server

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to currently do virtual hosting with node.js server (i.e. host multiple domains under one IP) ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sure, you can use [bouncy](https://github.com/substack/bouncy) or [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) specifically for that.

There's also an Express solution. [Check out this example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/vhost/index.js).

Comment: The github links gives me a 404

Comment: Try https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/vhost/index.js now instead :)

Comment: Read this, just setup node-http-proxy and I love it.  I use it on my local dev machine, where I'm now running 3 different node apps for actual use in-hose.  It was easy to setup, and seemed to be the most mature, though bouncy didn't look bad, but the fact node-http-proxy called out supporting WebSockets and other goodies did it for me.

Comment: I notice the Express example does a redirect.  in the example vhost provides they overwrite the value or req.url instead, but that doesn't seem to work for me.  however, I prefer it because redirect displays the new url on the browser and I want to keep the old url.  any thoughts as to why that might be?

Answer (score 21):

Web browsers send a the header property 'host' which identifies the domain host they are trying to contact.  So the most basic way would be to do:

```
http = require('http');

server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    switch(request.headers.host) {
        case 'example.com': response.write('<h1>Welcome to example.com</h1>'); break;
        case 'not.example.com': response.write('<h1>This is not example.com</h1>'); break;
        default: 
            response.statusCode = 404;
            response.write('<p>We do not serve the host: <b>' + request.headers.host + '</b>.</p>');
    }
    response.end();
});
server.listen(80);
```

Comment: This is the simplest explanation of what a virtual server/virtual host actually is. It's just about using the "Host:" header as a piece of routing information. So simple. Of course https and SNI make it a bit more interesting...

Answer (score 6):

I would recomend [express-vhost](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-vhost) because the others solutions are based on a proxy server, it means that each one of you vhost should open a different port.