# Basic idea behind node.js implementation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side

Here's my current theory as to how node.js will work:

1. I install node.js on my server so that it can interpret javascript files.
2. I then I write my javascript files and put them on my server (just as I would with PHP files).
3. I then interact with these files via my client-side javascript.

Obviously I've got something wrong, because I've been looking for a tutorial for the past hour or so which will teach me how to install it on my server - but they all seem to be focused on installing it locally.

Could someone give a dot-point rundown of how the final implementation will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You install it on a "server" as you would for any other machine -- with admin/root access via an [installer](http://nodejs.org/download/) or [package manager](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager).

Now, this assumes, by "server," you're referring to a computer. If, instead, you mean an existing "server application," such as Apache or IIS -- Node.js doesn't integrate directly with these. It primarily replaces them, allowing you to define the entire server application, from a rather low level, as a script.

Such a script can be found on the [project's homepage](http://nodejs.org/):

> This simple web server written in Node responds with "Hello World" for
>   every request.
>
> ```
> var http = require('http');
> http.createServer(function (req, res) {
>   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
>   res.end('Hello World\n');
> }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
> console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
> ```
>
> To run the server, put the code into a file `example.js` and execute it with the `node` program from the command line:
>
> ```
> % node example.js
> Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/
> ```

Beyond this example, you would want to inspect the [`req.method`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_method) and [`req.url`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url), typically via a [router](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/router) or [web framework](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/web-framework), to determine how to respond. [`express`](https://npmjs.org/package/express) or [`compoundjs`](https://npmjs.org/package/compoundjs) would be good options to start with.

You can still use other server applications as an HTTP proxy for Node.js, passing traffic along. But Node.js will still be running separately. If you're using IIS, there's even [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) which covers much of the setup for this.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Since posting the question I found that (apparently) I can't use node.js on my shared hosting account even if I have access to SSH. Does this sound correct to you? Apparently even if I did get it installed, I wouldn't be allowed access to certain ports.

Comment: @JoeRocc Yeah. You typically need a host that [explicitly supports Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3744294) or upgrade to a "*private*" or "*dedicated*" hosting plan so you have more control.

Comment: Sorry for the ridiculously late reply. Okay, so my whole node.js server (the computer) will run on one script? What if I want to have multiple websites? Does the user always with my server via the single node.js script, or do I somehow attach certain node.js files to different domains?

Comment: @JoeRocc Sounds like you're looking for virtual hosts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8503918/. You can run multiple `http.Server`s with one `node` process; they just have to be listening to their own port. The Express option can condense them further to just a single `http.Server`.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a server side JavaScript engine which enables you to build web server with JavaScript language. It is similar with PHP on Apache and C# on IIS. One thing different is that Node.js is event based that it does not create many threads as C# IIS does. So, Node.js has the potential of processing high concurrent requests. for Node.js tutorial you may refer to Node.js web site: http://nodejs.org/api/

> I then interact with these files via my client-side javascript.

I would disagree on this point with you, because what Node.js do is just create a web server, any interaction between server and client is HTTP based which means Node.js web server responses your requests from client side.

Comment: Okay, I learned this from the tutorials - but I'm not sure how to get started with the implementation on my server.

Comment: I suggest you try express.js http://expressjs.com/, it helps you to create a web server targeting on Node.js.