# node.js, express: limit to certain hostname

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having a bit of a hard time limiting my nodejs application to a serving a certain hostname. You can [specify the hostname](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) when calling server.listen() but internally I believe all this does is resolve the hostname to an IP address, even though the documentation states 'Begin accepting connections on the specified port and hostname'.

Take the following example:

```js
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello');
}).listen(3000, 'host.tld');
```

(Lets say host.tld resolves to 99.99.99.99)

That server will handle all requests that are sent to 99.99.99.99 on port 3000 regardless of the hostname.

So I would like to know a good approach to limiting my application to a specific hostname. My current solution is to check the hostname of the request and compare it to the hostname I want to serve.

Example (using express):

```js
// Limit all requests to the specified hostname.
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.host !== app.get('hostname')) {
    res.writeHead(404, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.end('Not found');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

This seems like a hack, although I haven't been able to find a better way to do it. Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend (for many other reasons) to have [NGINX](http://nginx.org/) as a reverse proxy in front of node.js.

Comment: @hgoebl so you'd specify your node app to listen on localhost and proxy a hostname to localhost:port? I really don't want to proxy anything and add another layer into my requests. Are you saying I can't specify hostname in node.js?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. But in many scenarios putting nginx to the front has a lot of advantages (SSL-offloading, delivering static content, load-balancing to node-cluster on same machine or different machines, solving Same-Origin-Policy problems, high availability). My comment in just a suggestion and not an answer ;-)

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I'm trying to understand the best way of doing this. I don't need to do any of that, I just want to limit my app to a certain hostname.

Comment: If you feel more comfortable (non-hacky), you could have a look at https://npmjs.org/package/virtual-host and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503841/

Comment: Thanks, based on my research and based on the replies to this thread, it's looking like I will either have to proxy in some form, or add another IP address to my server, as node.js cannot do this out the box (which I find odd) :( In my opinion, using a custom IP address is the only real non-hacky way.

Comment: @hgoebl in the end, i decided to go the nginx proxy route. it was relatively easy to setup. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here. Short answer is, it appears node.js cannot handle this 'natively' (ie, without additional application logic). If anyone disagrees, please let me know!

So my solution was to go the proxy route via Nginx. Here's my nginx config files:

https://gist.github.com/badsyntax/8455064

This answer may also be helpful to some: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5015178/492325

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a middleware instead of `all` verb with the same callback function:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.host && req.host !== app.get('hostname')) { // req.host may be undefined if the client did not send host header
    res.writeHead(404, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.end('Not found');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

This is the only way afaik to check for the accepted HTTP hostname.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping there was a solution at the node.js level rather than at application level. In the end I went with proxying via nginx.