# Running a node application with different domains

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing, multiple-domains

I have a node application that creates an API for the frontend to reference. Snippet below:

```
var app = express();

app.post("/api/login", function(req, res){  
  //login code
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Now if I go to `localhost:8080` everything works great as expected. However, I also have `local.framework` setup as a virtual host pointing to the frontend directory. When I visit `local.framework`, the website loads fine (it's finding the frontend stuff) but references to the API return 404 not found errors.

How can I ensure my domains are linked up with the node backend correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtual hosting with standalone node.js server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503841/virtual-hosting-with-standalone-node-js-server)