# Hosting multiple websites through multiple ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, iptables, portforwarding, cloud-hosting

I am using AWS to host my website currently (Ex.facebook.com). It is on node platform and runs on port 3000. I used Iptables to forward all port 80 incoming traffic to port 3000.

Now if I host another website on port 6000, can I forward the traffic to both ports 3000 and 6000 depending on the request?

Is there any script I have to write or I have provision in Iptables itself?

Comment: are you using a windows or linux vm?

Comment: linux - Ubuntu 14.04LTS to be exact

Comment: On returning requests to the client, how would you know which request gets mapped from subnet ip address to the clients internet ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Use virtual hosts (see [Virtual hosting with standalone node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503841/virtual-hosting-with-standalone-node-js-server)), unless you absolutely need to run multiple node installations on the same instance.  This way, your node app just needs to listen on one port, with the content mapped by URI host name.  That will put less load on the instance (fewer processes) and get rid of a potential routing nightmare.