# run 3 web servers on the same port

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-ec2, service, dns

Well i have a machine and i want to do a very simple thing, on this machine i have 3 DNS records,
for example 111.111.111.111 is the ip of the machine itself

```
test1.whatever.net - 111.111.111.111
test2.whatever.net - 111.111.111.111
test3.whatever.net - 111.111.111.111
```

- We would like the traffic coming through each DNS record to be
  handled by each corresponding service.
- Create 3 very simple scripts that act as a website using any language
  or platform (suggested NodeJs), that echo the name of the service
  when calling the DNS record (e.g. "service1", "service2" and
  "service3").

how do i do that?

- All of the services must run on port 80
- The machine is AWS Linux 2

Comment: Is it possible to change your "All of the services must run on port 80" requirement to "All of the services must be reachable through port 80"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What http server are you using?
Usually you can solve this issue with creating virtual hosts. In Apache it would look like this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html
There you can define, based on the DNS request, which folder the webserver should use to present the client.

Another option, but this might be more complex, when you setup an nginx proxy. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: i am using currently nodejs http module, this is kind of a test a friend gave me to challenge me, and i want to figure it out.

Comment: Did you check this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503841/virtual-hosting-with-standalone-node-js-server

Comment: Well you are right, after some research nginx rev-proxy is the answer, what i had to do is to use dokcer, after i ran nginx rev proxy on docker(using familiar nginx proxy form docker hub), i managed to run more containers with virtual host as environment related to the proxy container, and each container was nginx and i just copied html file into the 3 containers, and thats it :) of course you need to add dns to the hosts file. Thanks alot! you were my key to the solution!