# https.listen ignores hostname

Tags: node.js, express, https, hostname

I tried to bind the https server to my subdomain (cdn.somedomain.com). But https.listen(443, 'cdn.somedomain.com') ignores the hostname. He trys to bind the ip and thus all adresses.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
var router = express.Router();
var options = {
   key  : fs.readFileSync('/path/to/privkey.pem'),
   cert : fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert.pem'),
   hostname: 'cdn.somedomain.com'
};

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});
router.use(express.static('somefiles'));
app.use(subdomain('cdn', router));

https.createServer(options, app).listen(443, 'cdn.somedomain.com');
```

I already tried to use 'express-subdomain', how you can see in my code.

I hope you can help me.

Nils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want [virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting), where your server will only pass requests matching a particular hostname (*cdn.somedomain.com*) to the router.

You can use the [`vhost`](https://github.com/expressjs/vhost) module for that:

```
var vhost = require('vhost');
...
app.use(vhost('cdn.somedomain.com', router));
```

Answer (score 1):

The listen function is taking your hostname parameter and resolving it to an ip address, hence why it "ignores" the hostname.

source:
[node.js:: what does hostname do in `listen` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173091/node-js-what-does-hostname-do-in-listen-function)

Don't you want it to bind all addresses? Or are you trying to ignore your main domain?

Use your routers to handle the different domains:

```
var v1Routes = express.Router();
var v2Routes = express.Router();

v1Routes.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('API - version 1');
});
v2Routes.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('API - version 2');
});

router.use(subdomain('*.v1', v1Routes));
router.use(subdomain('*.v2', v2Routes));
```

This is right from the documentation:
https://github.com/bmullan91/express-subdomain